# YugabyteDB async replication in 2 different Azure regions behind load balancers

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I’m trying to setup async replication between universes running on CentOS VMs in different Azure regions behind Azure load balancer. I'm getting `connection refused` or `unable to establish connection to leader master`. I probably need help on understanding how & where to bind the correct IPs and which IPs to provide wherein the replication setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DB servers need to be able to talk with each other directly, not through load balancers. The IPs must be of the DB servers and the load balancers aren’t utilized between them. Load balancers can then be used between your clients & servers.